# Problem with getting directory on computer

Tags: macos, macos-mojave

My computer is a MacBook Pro with MacOS Mojave 10.14.5.

In the past, when I want to get some directory info of some specific folder. I would select the folder and use Command + I to open the get information page of the folder.

And copy the directory info from the 'where' of the 'General'. And I could copy the directory info directly to my code or command line to use it. But now, the directory info I can get turns out to be like this:

```
Where: ‎⁨Macintosh HD⁩ ▸ ⁨Users⁩ ▸ ⁨XXXXX ▸ ⁨Desktop⁩
```

which cannot be used directly.
Is there a solution to this to change it back so that I can copy paste and use it directly? Thanks!

Comment: Drag & drop is another solution

Answer (score 0):

CTRL-click the folder to open the context menu, then hold down the Option key. The *Copy "folder name"* option will turn into *Copy "folder name" as Pathname*.

Alternatively, you can enable Finder's path bar *View > Show Path Bar* (Option + Command + P), CTRL-clicking it and selecting *Copy "folder name" as Pathname*.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your method. The second one worked well but It seems that the second one has a little bit longer step than the first one. How could I use the first one? When I control click the folder. And copy the folder name is still the name itself.

Comment: So, the fastest way is probably: Select the folder, press **Option + Command + C**. This will copy the pathname to your clipboard. _After_ you CTRL-clicked the folder to open the context menu, you must hold down the Option key, then select _Copy "folder name" as Pathname_.